# Problem with dfs in multilevel analysis after converting data to long format

Tags: multilevel-analysis, degrees-of-freedom

I have a bit of an odd problem and would love to get some suggestions of what the cause could be as I am currently at a loss:
Some while ago, I had converted a dataset to long format in R using melt and calculated multilevel analyses with this data. Later, it cleaned up my code a bit and renamed some variables, but no substantial changes. I then just wanted to check the results from my analysis again and to my surprise, the dfs slightly changed. It's very subtle (mostly decimal places), but it's not the same. All other values remain unchanged. I have tried to find differences between my datasets, but there appear to be none (same distributions of values across factors, same number of rows, same data types & classes).
Can you think of anything that would slightly affect dfs in such a way? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Is everything else about the model (all parameter estimates, variance components, etc.) *identical* and only the dfs have changed? What is the *largest* change in the dfs? Also, are you using exactly the same version of the code (what package? `lme4`? on exactly the same version of R ?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is *melt*? A method, a `function` or a `package` (the latter two should be formatted `thus`)?